# How to mock an async function in nodejs using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

In the below function I have to mock httpGet function, so instead of call actual function and returning the value it should call a mock function

```
getStudents: async(req,classId) => {
  
  let result = await httpGet(req);
  return result;
},
```

My test case

```
describe('Mock',()=>{
    it('mocking api',async()=>{
        const result = await getStudents(req,classId);;
        console.log(result);
    })
})
```

Comment: An async function is just a function that returns a promise, you can mock it with e.g. `jest.fn()`: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue

Answer (score 0):

you can have the same `jest.fn()` as a mock for the function as you would do for a normal one.

then you can either implement your own Promise return value, or use jests's `mockResolvedValue` or `mockRejectedValue`

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue

For example:

```
import { httpGet } from 'http';
jest.mock('http'); // this is where you import the httpGet method from

describe('Mock',()=>{
    it('mocking api',async() => {
        httpGet.mockResolvedValue(mockresult); // httpGet should already be a jest.fn since you used jest.mock
        const result = await getStudents(req,classId);
        console.log(result);
    })
})
```

Comment: its not working I am not able to call the mock function @Tamas Kuzdi

Comment: what did you try @SunnySonar? please post some code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I would mock this as an ES6 module. In your tests, stick this at the top of your file

```js
jest.mock('http', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('http')
  return {
    __esModule: true, // necessary to tag this as an ES6 Module
    ...originalModule, // to bring in all the methods
    httpGet: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ /* the object you want returned */ })
  }
})
```